# SQL Group by With Case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, group-by

```
Name |  Amount | Date
_____________________
Jacob | 15 |    1-Oct-16

Jacob | 50 |    2-Oct-16

Ethan | 24 |    3-Oct-16

Jacob | 30 |    3-Oct-16

William |   17 |    1-Oct-16

William |   11 |    2-Oct-16

Ethan | 36 |    3-Oct-16

Ethan | 9 | 1-Oct-16
```

I have above table, and i want Sum of amount for last 5 days something like

```
Name | 5-oct-16 | 4-oct-16 | 3-oct-16 | 2-oct-16| 1-oct-16 
___________________________________________________________

Jacob | 0       | 0        |30         | 50        | 15
Ethan | 0       | 0        |60         | 0        | 9
William | 0       | 0        |0         | 11        | 17
```

want to group by on Name with amount sum of  last 5 days  separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE DATE WHEN '2016-10-05' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_2016105,
       SUM(CASE DATE WHEN '2016-10-04' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as amount_2016104,
       SUM(CASE DATE WHEN '2016-10-03' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as  amount_2016103,
       SUM(CASE DATE WHEN '2016-10-02' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as  amount_2016102,
       SUM(CASE DATE WHEN '2016-10-01' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) as  amount_2016101
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name;
```